# Can't remove vendors directory that was create by Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, directory

I'm sorry, but I really don't remember very well how I created this directory. I just remember I was trying to use chunks.

So, I have `vendors~.` directory, which was create by webpack. I can't see its contents. For example, if I use `ls` command in **PowerShell** it will return

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        10.07.2020     22:13                vendors~.
```

But if type `cd vendors~.` it says

```
+ cd vendors~.
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Yoskut...react\vendors~.:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

AND the problem is - I can't remove it. All I want is to get rid of this annoying `vendors~.` that does exist and does not in the same time.

---

Does anybody have any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know what the was that.

Windows itself couldn't remove this directory. Not with Explorer, CMD or Powershell. But, Ubuntu's terminal (for Windows) did it well.

So, if webpack someday create undeleteble folder, just use Ubunutu's terminal to destroy it